# SMS aggregation service provider

Tags: sms, aggregation

Can someone please tell me what are the pre-requisites for establishing an SMS Aggregation service (as a business), I am after the technology and implementation, a rough overview of what is involved (what components, ex. Gateway, carrier, etc) will be great help.

Regards

Comment: Not programming related. You are basically asking for us to give you a business plan. Try http://answers.onstartups.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Find partner(s) with the right infrastructure that offer you connection to the mobile world.  You will have difficulty dealing with carriers directly, but there are some "super-aggregators" that are connected to several carriers and offer you their services.  This partner deals for you with the low level stuff (routing & delivery on SS7 layer).  Get connected to the partner, probably via SMPP, the de facto standard protocol for SMS over IP.
- Find many good customers.  Offer them a broad range of interfaces like SMPP, HTTP, SOAP, ..., you name it.
- ...?
- Profit!

If you keep it like that you have an IP only infrastructure and you won't have to deal with the nasty parts of the SMS world (at least not technically).

Comment: Great pointers, Thanks. i was aching to get any information on this and your advice really helped. :)